# Recommendations for Flash to HTML5 conversion

Tags: flash, html

Before I get started on a very large project for creating audiovisual presentations in html5, I just wanted to check in with SO to see if there were any recommendations.  My company has a ton of fairly large flash videos that are essentially a person speaking while words appear on the screen with some animation that moves the words around.  Each video also has a menu that lists each part, a slider, and play/pause buttons (here is an example: http://www.gleim.com/accounting/cpa/tutorial.php )

In order to move toward supporting mobile browsers, we'd like the videos to be in something other than flash.  The idea we came up with was having an `<audio>` tag to play the audio and having the storyboard of the text/images and their timing decide what appeared on the screen (this would be handled by `<canvas>` or straight up DOM manipulation, etc.).  The problem is that we would not be able to simply convert our existing flash files to this format, we would only be able to use it from now on (this is not a dealbreaker).  The html5 version does not need to be at quite the same level of precision in terms of audio to visual timing either.

Using `<video>`s is out of the question.

So my question is:

- Is there a simple way to convert flash `swf` presentation-like files into html5?
- Failing that, is there an existing framework to essentially make html5 animate slideshows with sound?
- Is there some other alternative to this conversion that I have not considered.
- If I have to roll my own, are there any suggestions?

Comment: So, you're saying HTML5 features (video tag) aren't good enough (or something), yet you have to abandon Flash? I'd suggest the avoidance of extra work, embed Flash where needed, and move on. Flash is not going away on mobile or otherwise and will continue to be supported for bug and security fixes. Anyone saying otherwise is spreading FUD.

Comment: @Crusader the video tag would be fine, but it would be a lot of work, time, and memory for us to convert and maintain all of the video formats to make it work on all platforms.  We will probably end up having to keep flash anyway for good-old IE compatibility.  I thought that flash support was being dropped widely, though?

Comment: Right now we have a widespread misunderstanding (or anti-flash propaganda by certain bloggers?) of what Adobe has recently announced. They won't be upgrading Flash player for mobile devices, but it's not "end of life" (which would be cause for more concern). Too many drama queens just want to scream "Apple won", as if there were some Adobe vs Apple contest. Adobe is a major HTML5 company. Unlike Apple, they did not take sides on the matter. Flash will continue to be supported and updated on the desktop, where it makes much more sense, and is much more entrenched.

Comment: @Crusader even if that's the case, I still need to support iDevices

Comment: Understood (but I do believe that Adobe AIR runs on crippled Apple hardware, might want to look into whether that helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swiffy is one option (as above, note that it only supports a subset of Flash Player 8 and AS2), and [Adobe Wallaby](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/) is another, which is somewhat similarly limited - can only convert a subset of timeline animations (no AS2 or AS3 code) from a source FLA - http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Wallaby#Features_and_Support.  Going forward, however, Adobe has been working on HTML5 tools like [Adobe Edge](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/) that are purposed with (one day) equaling Flash's interactivity and animation capabilities with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

- See if [Google Swiffy](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) can convert your SWFs to HTML5 animations.
- Check out [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) for working with videos and creating overlays with JavaScript. Maybe you can do some kind of custom skin.